# Google App Engine MySQLdb connection ping

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine

We are running a python project on Google App Engine. Is there a way to ping our MySQLdb connection?

Our connections work but we want to ping our database using a task to make sure it is always up.

I have tried:

```
connection.ping()
connection.is_alive()
connection.is_connected()
```

None of them seem to work.

Thank you

**Edit**

I could not find a solution so I current do a query for a row in an important table and handle the results and errors. If you find/know a better solution please let me know.

Comment: Why would you like to ping your CloudSQL instance?

Comment: The MySQLdb that we use became corrupt and we lost access to all tables. We want to ping the connection to make sure that our database is up and that customers can continue to use our site.